# Delete 300k+ nodes from Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, nosql

I built a Neo4j database. It has the following property:

```
 +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+--+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+--+-+-+-
 +number of nodes used  + number of properties used + number of relationships used +
 +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+--+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+--+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
 +        1.000.085     +            4.000.133      +       2.599.838              + 
 +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+--+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+--+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

The size of my database is about 2 GB. 
Now I made a mistake: I added **300k** nodes but I have to delete them. Suppose the label of these nodes is *Label*.
 First of all, I tried the common:

```
match(n:Label)
delete n
```

And I had heap memory error.

Then I tried this:

```
   match(n:Label)
   with n limit 10000
   delete n
```

Then that 10000 was replaced with 20000, then 30000.... When I put 50000 I had out of heap memory error.

What can I do to delete these 300k nodes? I don't want to build again my DB, since I imported it from MongoDB.

Comment: Why do you increase the limit? Just stick with 10000 and run the statement until all the nodes have been deleted. Consider to amend `return count(n)` then you get back the number of nodes deleted.

Comment: It works , thank you . I do not understand a lot what that command does . It randomly chooses 10,000 nodes and then deletes them, isn't it?

Comment: since the comment helped you I assemble a reply below

Comment: if deleting 50k nodes exceeds your heap you should definitely up your memory for Neo4j. Usually deleting up to 1M nodes should be no problem with sensible heap sizes (2G or 4G)

Comment: With the following answer I solved my problem. But at first I tried to increase heap sizes. I created in `Z:\path\to\db\location\conf` the file `neo4j-wrapper.conf` and I set the following properties. 
`wrapper.java.initmemory=10240`
`wrapper.java.maxmemory=10240`
But Neo4j was not able to delete 50k nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to increase the limit. The limit bascially determines the size of the transaction. Since a transaction gets built up in memory before flushing to disc (upon commit), the maximum size of a transaction is determined by the amount of available java heap space.

```
match(n:Label)
with n limit 10000
delete n
return count(n)
```

This statement grabs the first 10000 nodes with a label of `Label` and deletes them. There is no defined order in which nodes are picked first.

After getting rid of the first 10k nodes, a subsequent invocation of the same statement again fetches 10k nodes and deletes them.

The `count` in the return reports back how many nodes have been processed. You invoke that statement until the reported value is 0 and all `Label` nodes are gone.